# Import sql file with template literal variables and execute with knex raw

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a large sql query that I'd like to move into a .sql file and then import and execute using `knex.raw()`.

so I have something like:

```js
knex().raw(`
  SELECT *
  FROM user_profiles
  WHERE user_id = '${userId}';
`);
```

I've tried moving the query into a file and reading it using

`let sql = fs.readFileSync('./queries/user-profile.sql').toString();`

But of course the template literal variable `${userId}` isn't evaluated.

I thought about regex and just replacing it manually, but I was hoping there would be a better way. Preferably a solution that handles the sql injection vulnerability created by doing this.

Thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use raw bindings: http://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings

```js
knex().raw(`
  SELECT *
  FROM user_profiles
  WHERE user_id = :userId;
`, {userId: 1});
```